# What is SoftPerfect LightWeight Filter in my Win7 network stack?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

After installing the drivers for my realtek wifi card, I have this item in my network stack:

SoftPerfect LightWeight Filter (Description: SoftPerfect NDIS LightWeight Filter).

I've googled, but can't find much info on what it is.  Does anyone know what it does?

Comment: Most likely a packet-capture driver for [one of these products](https://www.softperfect.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

An [NDIS Lightweight Filter driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is one of several driver models to monitor and filter network packets in Windows. Filter drivers can monitor and modify the interaction between protocol drivers and miniport drivers. A *miniport* is a type of hardware driver, part of the Windows Driver Model. These are USB, Audio, SCSI and network card adapters.

If an optional NDIS Lightweight Filter (LWF) driver is installed and the driver is not started, the network will not be available for up to 90 seconds.